# Estimating the capacity of unknown LiPo cell

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, identification, lipo

I recently salvaged this small (30 x 9.5 x 3.5 mm) LiPo single cell battery from an old device that lied broken for at least 3 years.

[image]

Therefore I expected it to be garbage ready for recycling, but when I measured its voltage it read 2.8V, so it seems to be in good shape. Hence I decided to keep it in my junk bin for experimentation purposes.

The problem is that I couldn't find any datasheet or info on the Internet, so estimating its capacity is a problem. In particular, I'm well aware of the LiPo charging technique that requires a constant-current phase followed by a constant-voltage phase, as [this TI application notes explains](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva557/snva557.pdf). Excerpts:

> At present, the major Li-Ion cell manufacturer recommends 4.200 +/- 50 mV as the ideal set point voltage, and 1c (a charging current rate equal to the A-hr rating of the cell) as the maximum charging current that can be used.
>
> [...]
>
> [image]

Since I never played a lot with LiPo batteries, I'm clueless at guessing its capacity (for what I know it could be anything between 100mAh and a couple of Ah).

Can anyone suggest me, if possible, a reasonable and *safe* estimate for its capacity or C rating, so that I won't be risking to overcharge it in the CC phase?

**EDIT** (to incorporate some more info, as prompted by comments)

- the cell weighs approximately 1g (something between 1g and 2g)
- it was embedded in an old (6-7 years) Bluetooth receiver for indoor usage (one of those small boxes that can be connected to the headphone jack of an amplifier to send the PC audio to your Hi-Fi system or whatever)
- as far as can be seen by close visual examination, it doesn't embed any protection circuitry

Comment: Weigh it. It'll be between 200 and 300 Wh/kg, probably on the low side for such a small cell. Divide by nominal voltage to get an Ah rating. Then charge at 0.5C to be on the safe side, at least the first time.

Comment: These are cheap cells with only about 150~300 mAh when used with a 10h Discharge but consult with Muni. About disposal. You might 1% if this now.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Nice suggestion. Unluckily the highest resolution scale I've got has a 1g resolution (3kg full range). It reads something between 1g and 2g. I fear the measurement is affected by too much error. Anyway, using 1g as its value, 200Wh/kg and 3.6V nominal voltage, I get 55mAh. Sounds reasonable?

Comment: This is a kind of cells used in micro-helicopters-quadcopters. For this size the cell capacity is about 120 mAh

Comment: Good enough for a first charge. Or you could make a Ng weight from cardboard , cut it into N pieces, and cut one of those in 10 to  increase resolution.

Comment: Keep in mind that these are usually "high discharge rate" cells, 10C to 15C, and unprotected, so accidental shorting is highly non-recommended.

Comment: @AliChen It came from an old Bluetooth receiver (at least 6yrs old), so probably not new technology (I doubt it was meant for high discharge, but I'm no expert). Nevertheless I've noticed, for what can be seen under that yellow tape, that it has no protection circuitry.

Comment: Charging at 50mA is unlikely to cause damage in the CC phase. This can help you get a curve that will let you estimate fairly closely its capacity.

Comment: [3.7V 110mAh 401030 Polymer Li-Po Rechargeable Battery For Mp3 Bluetooth PSP GPS](https://www.ebay.com/itm/3-7V-110mAh-401030-Polymer-Li-Po-Rechargeable-Battery-For-Mp3-Bluetooth-PSP-GPS-/121835108147)

Comment: @BruceAbbott Wow! I think you hit the spot! Searching for LP401030 battery datasheet I also found [this one](https://www.lipobattery.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/LP401030.pdf). The physical dimensions match and also the weight. The only apparent difference is the absence of the protection circuitry (PCM), unless it is buried in the pouch where it is not visible. I think that it is as good as it can get for an estimate of an unknown part! Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's not quite the same - the numbers are dimensions. 401030 is 4.0mm x 10mm x 30mm, yours is marked 500928, so is 5.0mm x 9mm x 28mm